# Formatting a recordset getString in a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using ADO to query a large table, and then put the recordset in to a String. The issue comes when I want to format that in a msgbox. My code looks like this:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon
rs.Open strSQL, cn
strSQL = "SELECT Employee, Skill_Level FROM [Employee$] 'more specific SQL after this

MsgBox "Employee/Skill Level" & vbNewLine & "-------------" & vbNewLine & rs.GetString, vbInformation, "Query Results"
```

When I do something like

```
dim blah As Variant
blah = rs.GetString
```

and set a breakpoint and hover over 'blah' during runtime, I get something like 'LastName FirstName MI☐5LastName FirstName3☐' and so on. The message box actually gets displayed like this:

```
Employee / Skill Level
----------------------
LastName FirstName MI     5
ReallyLongLastName FirstName MI 3
```

It typically ends up looking ok, except in cases where last or first names are longer. My question is, what's the best way to format that GetString so that the skill level field matches up when I have really long names in the query result?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
'pad the employee names with spaces
strSQL = "SELECT left(Employee + """ & String(40, "-") & """,40)" & _
     " as Employee, Skill_Level FROM [Employee$]"
```

you might have to fix the SQL a bit but you get the idea.

It will never be perfect alignment though due to Msgbox font being proportional (different space for different characters).

If you want a tidier output then create a userform and add a label with a non-proportional font such as Courier, and use that for the display.

Comment: Good suggestion, works great (using left). Didn't even think about doing it that way.